# String split Почему выскакиваеи исключение?

Tags: java

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String buf = new String("(888|775|531)");
    String[] tmp = buf.split("\\D");
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < tmp.length; i++)

        if(tmp[i] == "775"){
             System.out.println("second");
        }
        if(tmp[i] == "531"){
         System.out.println("third");
        }
        if(tmp[i] == "888"){
             System.out.println("first");
        }

    }
```

}

Comment: Оформляйте вопрос правильно. Не заставляйте других участников за вас определять, какое именно исключение "выскакивает". Дополните вопрос подробностями.

Answer (score 1):

Исключение было выход за пределы массива(не помню, как пишется на английском) из-за того, что проверялось только одно условие.

Во-первых, ваши условия поместите в тело цикла, все 3, а не только одно.

```
for (i = 0; i < tmp.length; i++){

        if(tmp[i] == "775"){
             System.out.println("second");
        }
        if(tmp[i] == "531"){
         System.out.println("third");
        }
        if(tmp[i] == "888"){
             System.out.println("first");
        }
}
```

А во-вторых, заместо равенства используйте метод equals(), тогда будет ещё лучше работать:
    tmp[i].equals("755")